# Open links of a HeroCard in the same tab

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I think by default every openUrl button in directline channel opens the site in a new tab, is there a way to specifically change one button to open in the same tab?

Thanks

Comment: It does not seem like this is possible after looking through the SDK code.  That is not to say you couldn't somehow hack together a solution.

Comment: Can you share your code? What did you try?

Comment: @nilsw I tried using an " formtarget="_self" " in the <button> tags but this affects every button including Postback and Imback

Comment: @Angelo Riega : Facing same issue: I want solution on this. Please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the WebChat control, modify it, build it, and host your own custom version.  The code that opens urls in a new window is here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/74eeec8ee2d73c83e388f739a502fe1042b93386/src/AdaptiveCardContainer.tsx#L57

```
if (action instanceof AdaptiveCards.OpenUrlAction) {
        window.open(action.url);  <-- this would need to be changed
    }
```